# Valid Keywords for Beginning a Java Source File

Tags: java

So far I know that these keywords are valid for beginning a java source file:

`class`, `public`, `import`, `package`, `interface`, and `final`

Additions from comments:  `abstract`, `strictfp`, `enum`

Are there any more?

(Thanks for all the super quick responses!  Feel free to edit this to add more that are found.)

Comment: this would make a good community wiki

Comment: is there any specific reason you ask this?

Comment: I ask because I'm in a classroom for Programming Principles 2 and the professor asked this to the class.  The answers he gave seemed incomplete to me (I listed his answers).

Comment: +1 for trying to make someone else look dumb. :P

Comment: It could be practically useful, for example, for a syntax highlighting editor to auto-detect Java files with minimal lookahead.

Comment: Finally, I just wanted to say thanks because this information gained me 4 bonus points on a test!  http://imgur.com/Oufx0.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Real modifiers you missed: `abstract`, `strictfp`
- Annotations like `@Retention`
- Annotation declarations: `@interface`
- Enumeration: `enum`
- Comments and whitespace
- As far as I know, nothing else
- Keep in mind that identifiers may use unicode escapes inside them, like `cl\u0061ss`

Comment: Heh, I thought of strictfp but then got distracted by trying to reformat the relevant portion of the JLS in Markdown.

Comment: Ooh strictfp is hardcore. Someone should write a code example of its usage.

Comment: The effects of `strictfp` are given here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#249198

Comment: in fact, it is not guaranteed that (the lack of) `strictfp` has an effect at all... And since you should not do any important (like financial) calculations with floating point values, I guess no one really needs strictfp...

Answer (score 4):

Annotations are valid
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

Examples

- @Preliminary @Copyright("2002 Yoyodyne Propulsion Systems")
- @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
- @Target(ElementType.METHOD)

Comment: But they're not exactly keywords.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget *abstract*

Answer (score 2):

How about `enum` ?

<del>How about `private` ?</del>

EDIT: Okay, that was my stupid blurt-out of the day.

Comment: can toplevel classes be private? What would that mean?

Comment: Cannot have a private class in java.

Comment: Private top-level classes don't even make sense. Private to whom?

Answer (score 1):

`abstract`

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant to include this in my list.  I had this written down.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Java > 1.5, **`enum`** as well.
As others mentionned, **`abstract`**.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the [keyword list](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), and a [modifier matrix](http://www.uni-bonn.de/~manfear/javamodifiers.php) now you only miss strictfp.

Answer (score 0):

Also from http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html, don't forget `@interface`!

**Edit:** Also, [`strictfp`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.1.3) applies to classes. See the [JLS §8.1.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.1):

> A class declaration may include *class modifiers*.
>
> ```
> ClassModifiers:
>     ClassModifier
>     ClassModifiers ClassModifier
>
> ClassModifier: one of
>     Annotation public protected private
>     abstract static final strictfp
> ```
>
> Not all modifiers are applicable to all kinds of class declarations. The access modifier `public` pertains only to top level classes (§7.6) and to member classes (§8.5, §9.5), and is discussed in §6.6, §8.5 and §9.5. The access modifiers `protected` and `private` pertain only to member classes within a directly enclosing class declaration (§8.5) and are discussed in §8.5.1. The access modifier `static` pertains only to member classes (§8.5, §9.5). A compile-time error occurs if the same modifier appears more than once in a class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [The Grammar of the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/syntax.html). From there you can infer all possible keywords.

You should start with *CompilationUnit*.

Comment: As the grammer is not exact, it will give you more possible words than are allowed in a Java program. Like the grammar allows `protected` or even `native` as first word, as does it allow an `abstract final class`.

Answer (score 0):

`module`. In JDK7. Perhaps. (Technically not a real keyword.)

(And is an empty file valid? As `package-info.java`? It's not really an interesting enough question for me to bother finding out.)

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget static and protected and javaDoc comments

Comment: static works only in "import static", but then it would be the second token... protected does not work at all (neither on imports nor on toplevel classes).

Comment: `static` and `protected` are not allowed on top-level classes. Javadoc comments are not keywords.

Comment: Don't static and protected go inside a class?

Comment: you can make static classes, which means they can be iniated as an object, they can only be referenced statically.

Comment: @Jay: Static classes are available in C#, but not in Java. In Java you can only have static inner classes (which do not need an instance of the outer class)